# spawn obstacles c# and accessing from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Getting a error when i try to instantiate in the manager class. saying
Error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Object' does not contain a definition for`GetComponent' and no extension method `GetComponent' of type`UnityEngine.Object' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: sorry how rude from me.. Done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `Obstacle` class:

```
void Start()
{
    manager = GameObject.FindWithTag("ObstacleManager").GetComponent<ObstacleManager>();
}
```

The tag obviously has to be the tag of the gameobject the manager is attached to.

Also: Always start class names with a capital letter (I did that in the snippet, keep that in mind, you will get an error right know with that).

Maybe you want to actually change your spawning a bit though. Have two lists, one for free spawnpoints and one for occupied. When you destroy an obstacle, pass the position to the spawning function to move the position to the free list.

**Edit**:

Another option to create the reference is to set it in your `ObstacleManager` on spawning. You need to grab a reference to the instantiated obstacle for this. I believe this should work without actually grabbing the obstacle gameobject, but you could do that too.

```
Obstacle obs = ((GameObject)Instantiate(TypeOfObstacles[j], pointsAvailiable[pointsIndex].position, Quaternion.identity)).GetComponent<Obstacle>();
obs.SetManagerReference(this);
```

And in `Obstacle` add

```
public void SetManagerReference(ObstacleManager obsManager)
{
    manager = obsManager;
}
```

For the free position you can do something like this:

```
// in Obstacle.cs
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    manager.SpawnNewObstacle(transform.position);    // you might be able to actually pass the transform, but I'm not sure if it will get destroyed before used in the other function
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

In the Manager:

```
public  int noOfObsacles;

public float[] xPercent;
public GameObject[] TypeOfObstacles;

float y;

// to keep track of which spawn points are free and which aren't use these lists
private List<Transform> freePositions;
private List<Transform> occupiedPositions;

private void Start()
{
    freePositions = new List<Transform>(spawnPoints);
    occupiedPositions = new List<Transform>();

    SpawnObstacles();
}

private void SpawnObstacles()
{
    // just use this for initial obstacles
    // call Spawn as often as needed
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfObstacles; i++)
    {
        Spawn();
    }
}

// you call this function from the obstacle that gets destroyed
public void SpawnNewObstacle(Vector3 freePos)
{
    // find the spawnpoint in the occupied points
    // and move it to the free ones since the obstacle got destroyed
    for(int i = 0; i < occupiedPositions.Count; i++)
    {
        if(occupiedPositions[i].position == freePos)
        {
            freePositions.Add(occupiedPositions[i]);
            occupiedPositions.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // and call Spawn
    Spawn();
}

private void Spawn()
{
    y = Random.value;
    int pointsIndex = Random.Range (0, freePositions.Count); 

    for (int j =0; j<xPercent.Length; j++)
    {

        if ( y <  xPercent[j])
        {
            // these 4 lines are essential for the spawning
            Obstacle obs = ((GameObject)Instantiate(TypeOfObstacles[j], freePositions[pointsIndex], Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Obstacle>();
            obs.SetManagerReference(this);
            occupiedPositions.Add(freePositions[pointsIndex]);
            freePositions.RemoveAt(pointsIndex);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really confused.. Can you kindly explain more...? :( is there another one of using findWithtag i really dont want to use that...

Comment: You need to create a reference to that other class. Since your obstacles are spawned on runtime, you can't populate that variable in the editor.

Comment: You can use find or actually you can set it during spawning too.

Comment: I edited my answer. This should get you started on how to get the connection. Im not sure if you can grab `Obstacle obs` directly on `Instantiate` or if you need the GameObject first and do this in another line. For a delayed spawn you can do something like `Invoke("Spawn", 5)`.

Comment: And the instantiation is simplified for the example. Just crank it up as wished.

Comment: Missed a `Spawn` at the end of `SpawnNewObstacle`. Added that.

Comment: Setting the reference like this is probably better than using any of the `Find/FindWithTag` functions.

Comment: An advise though: don't optimize to prematurely.

Comment: Obviously though in many situations you can only use one of those ways to set a reference. Setting it directly works well in combination with Instantiate.

Comment: With the updates it will spawn one new, but you can alter that by how often you call `Spawn`. E.g. in `SpawnObstacles` at the start I call `Spawn` with the value of `noOfObstacles`.

Comment: You shouldn't call it more often than there are free positions though obviously.

Comment: As mentioned I simplified the instantiation stuff for that example. You can crank it up with the percentage stuff and different type. `obstaclePrefab` is just a placeholder because I left out the different types.

Comment: Point is: you need to know which positions are free and which are occupied. You don't have anything for that in your code, just an array of all existing spawn points. I added the two lists for handling that. (You could actually remove your 'spawnPoints' array and make 'freePositions' public since I set it to 'spawnPoints' in start anyways.)

Comment: idk where to put it

Comment: You put it where you want to spawn your thing.

Comment: my noOfobstacle is 6 but it spawns 8  there is 2 extra obstacles spawning

Comment: I edited my answer, it should know be the complete `ObstacleManager` class.

Comment: @GunnarB. dude.  Do me a favour and vote this up, would you mind?!  https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/eliminate-unityscript-totally-and-forever  thanks!

Comment: @Alex dude you must not concern yourself with optimization.  Gunnar is giving you **amazing professional level code**.  All you should be doing is saying "thanks" dude.

Comment: Alex regarding that syntax error, you should actually copy and paste all of your "latest version" in to your question (Use "EDIT" button down bottom of your question).  Put in ALL the code file top to bottom and someone can tell you the minor error that is causing that.

Comment: I'm sorry that was rude from me. Ofcouse a huge thanks to gunnar and the question will be ticked.

Answer (score 0):

had a bracket issue! my bad

obstacle obs = ((GameObject)Instantiate(TypeOfObstacles[j], freePositions[pointsIndex].position, Quaternion.identity)).GetComponent();